# Finding the maximum number of parallelograms formed if a set of $x$ parallel lines and a set of $y$ parallel lines meet in $12$ points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> There is a set of parallel lines with $x$ lines in it and another set
> of parallel lines with $y$ lines in it. The lines intersect at $12$
> points. If $x>y$, find the maximum number of parallelograms that can
> be formed.

My solution approach :-
As there are $12$ points which we are getting after the intersection of $x$ parallel lines with the $y$ parallel lines, then it should mean that $xy=12$. `Please confirm me on this if I am correct or not?`

Now I solved this question diagrammatically i.e. taking $12$ points formed by intersection of some $x$ parallel lines with the $y$ parallel lines and then counting all the possible parallelograms in the diagram and I counted a maximum of $18$ parallelograms that can be formed in this condition and my answer is correct !

But I was thinking how this question can be solve mathematically, without doing any manual counting for some bigger numbers of intersection points; let's say there are $50$ intersection points or $1000$ intersection points? Also is there any importance of $x>y$? How it would have impacted the answer if the relation would have been $y>x$? Is there a way to solve this question mathematically in bigger number scenarios? Please clarify me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: From a solution-verification POV, you have not included enough details. The numerical answer is correct (and if that's all you're going for, great), but the proof part leaves a lot to be desired. EG How do you know that you have considered all possible arrangement of 12 points (esp since that wasn't referenced explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

Given: The lines intersect at $12$ points

Therefore $x \cdot y = 12$. Since $x > y$ possibilities are $x = 6$ and $y = 2$ or $x = 4$ and $y = 3$.

We need $4$ points to form a parallelogram, $2$ points forming $1$ line and the other $2$ points forming the other line.
When $x = 6$ and $y = 2$, the number of parallelograms formed $= {}_6C_2 \cdot _2C_2
= 15 \cdot 1$

When $x = 4$ and $y = 3$, the number of parallelograms formed $= _4C_2 \cdot _3C_2 $

Compute this and get the answer